# Given $B=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ basis what is the necessary condition so that $C=\{v_1+v_2,v_2+v_3,...,v_n+v_1\}$ will also be a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Given $B=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$, a basis in $\mathbb{R^n}$ what is the necessary condition so that $C=\{v_1+v_2,v_2+v_3,...,v_n+v_1\}$ will also be a basis in $\mathbb{R^n}$?

The answer to this question has to use the fact $\mathbf{(1)}$ that matrix $A_{n \times n}$ of form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&.&.&.&.&1 \\
1&1&0&.&.&.&0\\
0&1&1&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&.&.&0&1&1&0\\
0&.&.&.&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

has det$(A)=0$ if $n$ is even while det$(A) \neq0$ if $n$ is odd.

We can see that $A$ can be received from $I_n$ after the operations that are described in $C$. I'm not sure how to prove this for any basis which is not the same as $I_n$. If I could prove that $C$ is row equivalent to $A$ I could use (1) for proof.

Comment: You don't really need to choose a basis, in THE basis they give you, this is exactly true. Don't bother with going to other bases.

Comment: @CameronWilliams but I need to prove this for any basis for example where $v_1=(2,0)$, $v_2=(2,2)$

Comment: You don't though. You misunderstand bases. In the basis of $v_1,...v_n$, the matrix is exactly correct. It doesn't matter what those vectors are. The matrix is defined RELATIVE to the basis.

Comment: @CameronWilliams the original problem has 2 parts: first where I have to find for which values of $n$ $A$ is invertible. the second part is where I have to prove this for $B$ and $C$ which is the question of my post.

Comment: @CameronWilliams but $A$ is of a very special form where we have lots of zeroes. As far as I understand I need to prove this for any $C$ which is not necessarily of such "comfortable form". How can I prove that $C$ is equivalent to $A$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams the first part is the fact (1) which is part of my post.

Comment: A generalization of the problem (with solution) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107116/for-which-n-k-is-s-n-k-a-basis-fun-algebra-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do everything with determinants, you can reason as follows: if $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then its columns form a basis of $\Bbb R^n$ if and only if $\det(M)\neq0$. Now if $B,C$ are the matrices whose columns describe (in coordinates) the $n$-tuples of vectors of the same name, then by construction $C=B\cdot A$, and so $\det(C)=\det(B)\det(A)$. It is given that $B$ describes a basis, so $\det(B)\neq 0$; then $\det(C)\neq0$ if and only if $\det(A)\neq0$, which apparently you know to be the case if and only if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the direction I was looking for! But why can we say that $C=AB$?

Comment: Sorry, $C=BA$ instead. That is column $j$ of C is $B$ applied to column $j$ of $A$, which forms a linear combination of the columns of $B$; for instance for $j=1$ that is the sum of the first two columns.

Comment: Could I say that for $C_{ij}=(BA)_{ij}=b_{ii}a_{ii}+b_{i,i+1}a_{i+1,i}+b_{1n}a_{nn}$?

Comment: More like $C_{i,j}= (BA)_{i,j} =b_{i,1}a_{1,j}+b_{i,2}a_{2,j}+ \cdots ++b_{i,n}a_{n,j}$, which is coordinate $i$ of $B\,v$ with $v$ equal to column $j$ of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ spans a vector space $V$, then for any linear transformation $A$, $\{Av_1, \ldots, A v_n \}$ spans the image of $A$; $A$ is invertible iff its image spans $V$, so $\{A v_1, \ldots, A v_n\}$ spans $V$ iff $A$ is invertible. For sets of $n$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space, of course, "spans $V$" and "is a basis of $V$" are equivalent. For your particular matrix $A$, we have $A v_1 = v_1 + v_2$, $A v_2 = v_2 + v_3$, and so forth, *for any set of vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$*, not just for the standard basis. You should be able to draw conclusions from here.